# Is this a functor?Is this a useful functor?

Tags: algebraic-topology

To every topological space $X$ we  associate a  sequence of groups $G_{n}(X)$ as follows:

There is  a natural morphism $\alpha_{n}:\pi_{n}(X)\to \pi_{n+1}(SX)$ which maps  each $\gamma:S^{n}\to X$ to $S\gamma:S(S^{n})\simeq S^{n+1} \to SX$  where $S$ is the suspension operator acting on spaces and  maps.

We  define $G_{n}(X)=\pi_{n}(X)/\ker \alpha_{n}$.

Is $X \mapsto G_{n}(X)$  a  functor? Is it a useful   functor(in the following sense):

Are there two connected topological spaces $X,Y$ with the same homotopy groups(of all order) but there is  a  natural number $n$  such that $G_{n}(X) $  is  not isomorphic to $G_{n}(Y)$?

Comment: It might be useful in that sense, but it might also be hard to compute. A much more useful construction along these lines is stable homotopy, which has the distinct advantage of being a homology theory.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  thank you  for your comment on stable homotopy.